# xkvltxp gives keyval error in case of biblatex's options on multiple lines

Tags: biblatex, package-options, key-value

A `keyval` error arises if both:

- `xkvltxp` is loaded
- `biblatex` is loaded with options on multiple lines.

The following MWE shows this strange behavior:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{xkvltxp}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=numeric]{biblatex}
\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

works like a charm but, if the `xkvltxp` is loaded, it gives the error:

```
! Package keyval Error: style undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10902 \blx@processoptions
```

As soon as the `biblatex`'s options are given on the same line, this file compiles like a charm.

I tried some other packages than `biblatex` with options on multiple lines but it is the only one I found giving this eror.

Comment: I can confirm that I get the exact problem you mention when using a version of `keyval` (MikTeX 2.9, `biblatex` 2.8). There were some [`keyval`-related problems](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175982/35864) not too long ago, not sure whether that has anything to do with your problem though.

Comment: Yes, it happens as you're reporting. `:(` Do you really need `xkvltxp`?

Comment: @moewe It's not related to the recent keyval update, the same happens in texlive 2013

Comment: It is unrelated to biblatex, as far as I can see _all_ package option handling becomes sensitive to white space if xkvltxmp is loaded eg `\usepackage[ dvips ]{color}` makes an error that the option ` dvips ` is not known as the spaces are taken as part of the option name.

Comment: I mailed Hendri:-)

Comment: @egreg I need it in a class of my own. Well, at least I was sure about that and now, I'm not that sure :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle At least `\usepackage[ detect-family ]{siunitx}` doesn't make any error, but maybe that's because `siunitx` is a LaTeX3 package...

Comment: @DenisBitouzé the standard option handler removes all space, but kv versions usually don't so you can do `foo=a b c, ...` but they need to remove space around `,` and `=` while parsing, but what I think happens here is if you load xkvltxp but _don't_ use a keyval parser on the option list then the white space is kept.

Comment: I was happy to see a new version of `xkeyval` uploaded to CTAN and in TeX Live; I upgraded and now the example gives an error during loading of `kvoptions`. `:(` The error disappears if `kvoptions` is loaded before `xkvltxp`.

Comment: @egreg Well, I still have same error, with an up to date TL 2014 (`kvoptions` 2011/06/30, `keyval` 2014/05/08, `xkvltxp` 2004/12/13).

Answer (score 4):

There is package `kvoptions-patch`. It tries to be much more conservative than `xkvltxp`. It only assumes that there might be `key=value` pairs to protect the `value` part (from expansion, category code changes, ...).

The following example works

```
\RequirePackage{kvoptions-patch}
\documentclass[myoption={val1,val2}]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=numeric]{biblatex}  
\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

with the expected warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [myoption={val1,val2}].
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as pointed out in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188265/migrating-from-xkeyval-to-kvoptions-how-to-retrieve-definechoicekey, my class currently makes use of `xkeyval` features and just adding `\RequirePackage{kvoptions-patch}` leads to lots of errors.