# Migrating from xkeyval to kvoptions: how to retrieve \define@choicekey?

Tags: documentclass-writing, class-options, xkeyval, kvoptions, xkvltxp

I'm in the process of migrating a class I wrote from `xkeyval` to `kvoptions`, mainly because I'd like to provide class options whose values could be list of comma separated values:

```
\documentclass[myoption={val1,val2}]{myclass}
```

and, for this, `xkeyval` needs `xkvltxp` which is [currently buggy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178762/18401).

I'd like to know if there is any tutorial that explains how perform this migration, especially how to deal with `xkeyval`'s `\define@choicekey` macro. Another questions are about:

- `+` extension of `xkeyval`'s macros that allow to deal with unexpected values passed by the user,
- `\ExecuteOptionsX` and `\ProcessOptionsX` equivalents.

Comment: As things stand this is too broad. `xkeyval` does 'general' key-value input whereas `kvoptions` is rather more focussed on a smaller number of common entry types. The net result is that replacing `xkeyval` by `kvoptions` will also require hand-coded keys using just `keyval`, and thus an answer here would have to be an entire guide to creating keyval input!

Comment: Could you argue, why you want to migrate? There seem to be other packages available, such as [l3keys2e](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3keys2e), [ltxkeys](https://ctan.org/pkg/ltxkeys), and [skeyval](https://ctan.org/pkg/skeyval). All possible alternatives seem to be listed at https://ctan.org/recommendations/kvoptions.

Comment: All possible alternatives seem to be listed at https://ctan.org/recommendations/kvoptions. There is also a "A guide to key-value methods" by Joseph Wright, second draft for TUGBoat,
2009-03-17. http://www.texdev.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/keyval.pdf. OK, I recommends kvoptions or [pgfkeys](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfkeys), where [pgfkeyx](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfkeyx) is an extended version of.

Comment: @koppor At the time of asking, the reason was I to provide class options whose values could be list of comma separated values (I didn't succeed to do so with `xkeyval`). Meanwhile, I switched to `l3keys2e` for new classes (but couldn't find time to switch the concerned class).

Comment: @denis-bitouzé Is "Programming key–value in expl3 by Joseph Wright" the documentation one should go for or do you recommend something else?

Comment: @koppor Indeed, but as well as other `LaTeX3` documentations (especially `interface3.pdf`).